# ngTable shows the first column only

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ngtable

I'm trying to update my ngTable with ngTableParams but only the first column is displayed.

js code:

```
var dataset = [
  {name: "Hello50", bunny:"Bunny1", age: 50},
  {name: "Hello49", bunny:"Bunny2", age: 49},
  {name: "Hello48", bunny:"Bunny3", age: 48},
  {name: "Hello47", bunny:"Bunny4", age: 47},
  {name: "Hello46", bunny:"Bunny5", age: 46},
];

/** @export */
this.tableParams = new ngTableParams({count: 10}, { data: dataset});
```

and html:

```
>   <table ng-table="ctrl.tableParams" class="table" show-filter="true">
>     <tr ng-repeat="user in $data">
>       <td data-title="'Name'" > {{user.name}} </td>
>       <td data-title="'Bunny'" > {{user.bunny}} </td>
>     </tr>   </table>
```

It shows the 1st (Name) column only.

If I print out

```
<h1>{{ctrl.tableParams}}<br></h1>
```

then it shows:

> {"data":[{"name":"Hello50","va":"Bunny1","ua":50},{"name":"Hello49","va":"Bunny2","ua":49},{"name":"Hello48","va":"Bunny3","ua":48},{"name":"Hello47","va":"Bunny4","ua":47},{"name":"Hello46","va":"Bunny5","ua":46}]}

Why is it "va" and "ua"? I expected "bunnny" and "age" there.

Please help. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

According to the [docs](http://ng-table.com/#/), the only typo that i'm seeing is:

this.tableParams = new ngTableParams({count: 10}, { **data**: dataset});

You should use dataset instead.

Please see the following snippet.

```js
    angular.module("sample", ["ngTable"])
      .controller("myController", myController);

  var dataset = [
      {name: "Hello50", bunny:"Bunny1", age: 50},
      {name: "Hello49", bunny:"Bunny2", age: 49},
      {name: "Hello48", bunny:"Bunny3", age: 48},
      {name: "Hello47", bunny:"Bunny4", age: 47},
      {name: "Hello46", bunny:"Bunny5", age: 46},
    ];

    myController.$inject = ["NgTableParams"];

    function myController(NgTableParams) {

      this.tableParams = new NgTableParams({}, {
        dataset : dataset
      });
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/ng-table@3.0.1/bundles/ng-table.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div ng-app="sample" class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-3" ng-controller="myController as demo">
      <h3>ngTable</h3>
      <table ng-table="demo.tableParams" class="table table-condensed table-bordered table-striped">
        <tr ng-repeat="user in $data">
          <td data-title="'Name'" filter-data="demo.nameFilter">{{user.name}}
          </td>
          <td data-title="'Bunny'" filter-data="demo.descriptionFilter">{{user.bunny}}
          </td>
          <td data-title="'Age'" filter-data="demo.descriptionFilter">{{user.age}}
          </td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use dataset:dataset instead of data:dataset

```
this.tableParams = new ngTableParams({count: 10}, { dataset: dataset});
```

codesample - https://codepen.io/nagasai/pen/NMgGMb

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', ['ngTable']);
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope, NgTableParams) {
    $scope.firstName = "John";
    $scope.lastName = "Doe";
  var dataset = [
  {name: "Hello50", bunny:"Bunny1", age: 50},
  {name: "Hello49", bunny:"Bunny2", age: 49},
  {name: "Hello48", bunny:"Bunny3", age: 48},
  {name: "Hello47", bunny:"Bunny4", age: 47},
  {name: "Hello46", bunny:"Bunny5", age: 46},
];

/** @export */
$scope.tableParams = new NgTableParams({count: 10}, { dataset: dataset})
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.9/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ng-table/1.0.0/ng-table.min.js"></script>
<body>

<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">

  <table ng-table="tableParams" class="table" show-filter="true">
 
   <tr ng-repeat="user in $data">
      <td data-title="'Name'" > {{user.name}} </td>
      <td data-title="'Bunny'" > {{user.bunny}} </td>
     </tr>   </table>

</div>


</body>
```